# How to get a string value from a JToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm getting data from a web service that returns a JSON response.
This is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var result =  client.DownloadString("http://some url");
    
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(result);

// Location l = new Location();
//   l.city = obj["ad"][2]; error here
```

At this point it returns a result, but I am getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'string'

I would like some assistance getting the returned data into my variable in the model.

This is my JSON:

```
{
  data: [
  {
    address_obj: {
    street1: "9518 Front Beach Road",
    street2: "",
    city: "Panama City Beach",
    state: "Florida",
    country: "United States",
    postalcode: "32407",
    address_string: "9518 Front Beach Road, Panama City Beach, FL 32407"
  },
```

Comment: If you debug your code is a value being returned and assinged to the obj object?

Comment: yes,it works well @Lima

Comment: Can you include your Location class and a sample of the JSON?

Comment: what's the string result of `DownloadString`?

Comment: I have added my json and I want to call for the city object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The JSON represents an outer object containing a `data` array of objects, with each item containing an `address_obj` object which then has string properties.  So the `JToken` indexer syntax you use has to match that hierarchy, including using the correct property names.  Also, when retrieving the value from a `JToken` you need to cast it to the correct type.

You can get the city like this, where `i` is the index of the location you want:

```
l.city = (string)obj["data"][i]["address_obj"]["city"];
```

However, if all you're doing is populating model objects, it is probably simpler to deserialize directly to those using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` rather than manually populating them using `JTokens`.  For example, if your classes are defined like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Item> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("address_obj")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("street1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("street2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("postalcode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("address_string")]
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize directly to them like this:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

Comment: just to know please tell me if there isn't a root object then how to call.

Comment: @anu There is always some kind of root object.  It may not be this exact root object, but something must always be at the root of the JSON.  So if it's something different then you use a different class.  If it's an array then you use an array or list of the class.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to get JToken and JArray as a string.

Use Formatting.None for simple formatting.

```
string json = "[\"a\", null, \"b\", null, null, null, 0,[],[[\"c\"], null,[0],[\"d\"]]]";
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
    // array string
    string arrayStr = array.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        JToken elem = array[i];
        // token string
        string jtokenStr = elem.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    }
```

Comment: `Formatting.None` did the tricks! Thank you

Comment: I've messed around with this for hours and elem.ToString made my day.

Comment: Thank you, this is how I interpreted the Title. "Turn a JToken back into a Json String"

Answer (score 0):

You can add those class models to your app, and deserialize the json to it, you can use various types of deseriallizers, personally I like newtonsoft's json.net, here are the classes:

```
public class AddressObj
{
    public string street1 { get; set; }
    public string street2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
    public string address_string { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public AddressObj address_obj { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

After that deserialize the response to AddressObj and access the city property

Comment: yours is  a half answer :)

Comment: then what to go, help with this

Comment: @anu start with this, their documentation is pretty good, see the serialization section:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DataObj
{
    [JsonProperty("prop_1")]
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
}
//Select is from Linq
var data = e.details.Select(a => a.ToObject<DataObj>()); // e.details is a JArray

 //json is like -----
{
   "prop_1": "text"
}
```