# Using selectToken with String C#

Tags: c#, string, json.net

I got a json containing lots of data and one of it fields is `name`.

I want to get data from specific places in this json using the next loop:

```
            while (y < i - 1)
            {
                string Price = string.Format("{0}.name", list_MainId[y]);
                list_Price.Add(Url_Parsed.SelectToken(Price));
                Console.WriteLine(Price);
                Console.ReadKey();
                y++;
            }
```

`list_MainId` contains int numbers like 145,167 and more.
The Price string that i want to get is for example:

```
145.name
167.name
```

However, when i try to get the data from the json inserting the string Price i get the following error:

```
"cannot convert from Newtonsoft.json.Linq.JToken to string"
```

Is there a way i can format a string by adding it a variable like `list_MainId` and then being able to still use it in my json?

Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754692/how-to-get-a-string-value-from-a-jtoken

Comment: saw this mate, im not sure its what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get string from JToken

```
Url_Parsed.SelectToken(Price).ToObject<string>();
```