# How to get key value from input json in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

i have a json in below format

```
  {{
      "encoding_version": 1,
      "root": {
        "_type": "dictionary",  
        "test1": 0,
        "test2": 6593,
        "test3": ".key.test",
        "test4": "key.test",
        "test5": ".key.14",     
        "test6": 6159
      }
    }}
```

i am trying to get `"test5"` value which is 14

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputJson);
var id = data["test5"];
```

however getting it null,Please help.

Comment: Or https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ayaru

Comment: Could you please provide a **valid** json? You can use [this website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check validity.

Comment: You can use `data.SelectToken("root.test5")` as shown in [JSON.NET JObject - how do I get value from this nested JSON structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40538001/3744182).  Or use the null-conditional `?[]`: `data["data"]?["test5"]` as shown in [Json.NET get nested jToken value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42290485/3744182).  Then to get a string value you can cast the return to a `string` as shown in [How to get a string value from a JToken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33754692/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

You have provide JSON with two times curl braces, i have made this small correction in your input JSON :

```
{
  "encoding_version": 1,
  "root": {
  "_type": "dictionary",
  "test1": 0,
  "test2": 6593,
  "test3": ".key.test",
  "test4": "key.test",
  "test5": ".key.14",
  "test6": 6159
  }
}
```

As your deserialization is correct and you are looking for value of `"test5"` which is `".key.14"`. Your desired key is two level down in JSON i.e. first go for `"root"` and then `"test5"`. Hence your code will look like:

```
string test5Value = (string)result["root"]["test5"];
```

output => .key.14

If you want 14 then you might need to split output string and take out the required value.